# Setting AssemblyFileVersion with MSBuild-call?

Tags: msbuild, build-process, automation, versioning, assemblyinfo

We have a batch-based buildprocess and we are using MSBuild only for compiling our project-files from visual studio. We also have integrated wix into our build-process. To set the version of our software we specify in the main-build-script some environment variables, that we use during the build-process.
My problem is, that i have to set the FileVersion of the Assembly (AssemblyFileVersion) in my assembly-informations.
Is there a way to give the MSBuild-call a property with the version to set? Like this (this doesn't work):

```
%dotnetdir%msbuild.exe Viewer.csproj /property:Configuration=Release /property:Platform=AnyCPU /property:AssemblyFileVersion=%major%.%minor%.%build%
```

The resulting assembly should have the fileversion `%major%.%minor%.%build%`.
It's pain for me to set the AssemblyFileVersion-setting in all projects. And a program which is doing this is against my philosphy (i don't want to change my source with automated processes). The version should be set through the build-script. It is not necessary that the AssemblyFileVersion is set in the AssemblyInfo.cs

Or is there a possibility with MSBuild to specify a xml-configuration-file which describes the assembly-informations?

Would be great if there are any advices.

greetings, thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Version` and `AssemblyInfo` tasks from the [MSBuild Community Tasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) project may help.

Comment: Any example of this in action? Tried on a .wdproj and the referenced assemblies did not update the version.